# Help with Maclaurin series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm stuck on this problem.

**Find the Maclaurin series of $\frac{x}{1-x^3}$ and use it to find an easy expression for the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (3n+1)x^{3n}$ and explain for which interval this applies.**

Using a well know series, I just substitute and multiply by x

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n=\frac{1}{1-t}$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{3n+1}=\frac{x}{1-x^3}$

I struggle with the other part of the problem, does anyone have some tips?

Comment: You've got an expression with $3n+1$ in the exponent. You WANT an expression that has $3n$ in the exponent, and $3n+1$ as a coefficient. Can you think of an operation you're familiar with that might do this?

Comment: Ohhhhhh, differentiate. I should have seen that! Thank you so much! By the way, what do they mean by finding the interval that this sum applies? Why won't it work for any number x?

Comment: No, it won't. There are a whole lot of theorems about radius of convergence of power series, and when it's OK to differentiate or integrate term-by-term, and you'll need to use one or more of these. Just to give a very concrete example, in the pre-differentiation formula, the two sides are evidently different for $x = 1$ (just plug in to see why), and even worse for $x = 2$, where the value on the right is negative, and the value on the left is an infinite sum -- a divergent sum! -- all of whose terms are positive.

Comment: @Mathomat55 : The series you used for $\frac{1}{1-t}$ only converges for some $t$, not all $t$.  For instance it diverges for $t = 2$ because the terms, $t^n$, do not go to zero in the limit of large $n$.  This behaviour is carried through your computation.  Also, any time you have a new power series, you should find out where it converges; most power series only converge on an interval, and using them outside that interval fails.

Comment: Thank you so much @JohnHughes. I think I understand it now. Really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Thank you also, @EricTowers :)

Comment: Help with... help with... help with..., help with: your questions read like a menu of "help with "do this for me" questions.  Hopefully, you've moved beyond "help with (doing this for me) sorts of questions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{3n}= \frac{1}{1-x^3.}, |x|<1~~~~(1)$$
D.W.r.t $x$ bith sides to get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3n~ x^{3n-1}=\frac{3x^2}{(1-x^3)} ~~~~~~~(2)$$
Multiply by $x$ on both side to get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3n ~x^{3n}=\frac{3x^3}{(1-x^3)^2}~~~~~~~(3)$$
Adding (1) and (3), we get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (3n+1) x^{3n} =\frac{1+2x^3}{(1-x^3)^2}~~~~(4)$$

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation!